# Qml applying animation and add text to Slider bar

Tags: animation, qml, slider

I am learning Qml newly and i am trying to customize a slider as below

[Animation to SliderBar & Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W480v.png)

And i was unable to figure the part how to apply animation or color the slider with thick red when slider handle is being dragged and apply fade out animation to text in parallel when the slider handle is being dragged.

I tried with ColorAnimation to achieve the coloring slider when handler is dragging and text part not able to figure out.

Attaching the code that i tried to achieve the expectation

```
Slider{
                id:control

                background:  Rectangle{
                    x: control.leftPadding
                    y: control.topPadding + control.availableHeight / 2 - height / 2
                    implicitWidth: 331
                    implicitHeight: 68
                    width: control.availableWidth
                    height: implicitHeight
                    radius: 10
                    color: '#cc0000'
                    //opacity: 0.4
                    border.color: "#cc0000"

                    Rectangle{
                        width: control.visualPosition * parent.width
                        height: parent.height
                        color: "blue"
                        radius: 10
                    }
                }

                handle: Rectangle {
                    id: sliderHandle
                    property int fnValu : control.leftPadding  + control.visualPosition * (control.availableWidth- width)
                    x: control.leftPadding  + control.visualPosition * (control.availableWidth- width)
                    y: control.topPadding + control.availableHeight / 2 - height / 2
                    implicitHeight: 70
                    implicitWidth: 88
                    radius: 10

                    Text{
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: "SOS"
                    }
                    gradient: Gradient {
                        GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: '#990000' }
                        GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: '#cc0000' }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Attaching image of what i was able to achieve

[What i achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgBxo.png)

If anyone now's how to render the text and apply fade out animation to the text when slider handle is being dragged, help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: If you will check the [Slider customizing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-slider) doc you can see that close to your need, i.e. the color before the handle is different so you can base on this example you own one.

Comment: @folibis - Thanks for link and input that help a lot, now i have to figure out the text animation part.

Comment: Hi, did you get your answer? And did you consider about using a **Switch** rather than a **Slider**?

Comment: Hi @SMR, i got the answer from Rouven post. Thanks for suggesting switch will take a look on that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the animation on the fading out your text. You could do the following without even the need of an animation react to onPositionChanged of the slider and change the opacity property of the text.
Edit: Adjusted my answer to your code changes.

```
            Slider{
                        id:control
                        onPositionChanged:{
                            backgroundText.opacity = 1-position
                        }

                        background:  Rectangle{
                            x: control.leftPadding
                            y: control.topPadding + control.availableHeight / 2 - height / 2
                            implicitWidth: 331
                            implicitHeight: 68
                            width: control.availableWidth
                            height: implicitHeight
                            radius: 10
                            color: '#cc0000'
                            //opacity: 0.4
                            border.color: "#cc0000"

                            Rectangle{
                                width: control.visualPosition * parent.width
                                height: parent.height
                                color: "blue"
                                radius: 10
                            }
                            Text{
                                id:backgroundText
                                text: "Slide to Send"
                                color:"black"
                                anchors{
                                    centerIn: parent
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        handle: Rectangle {
                            id: sliderHandle
                            property int fnValu : control.leftPadding  + control.visualPosition * (control.availableWidth- width)
                            x: control.leftPadding  + control.visualPosition * (control.availableWidth- width)
                            y: control.topPadding + control.availableHeight / 2 - height / 2
                            implicitHeight: 70
                            implicitWidth: 88
                            radius: 10

                            Text{
                                anchors.centerIn: parent
                                text: "SOS"
                            }
                            gradient: Gradient {
                                GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: '#990000' }
                                GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: '#cc0000' }

                            }
                        }
                    }
```